# Unlock a migrated question when it is deleted from the original site

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154721/runtime-error-for-meta-so was migrated from *Stack Overflow* to its meta site, and closed as too localised. The question on the meta site is now locked as rejected migration, but the question on *Stack Overflow* has been deleted from the OP.

In such cases, the question in the site receiving it should be unlocked, to allow it to be deleted from users who can vote to delete it without the intervention of a diamond moderator.

Comment: Mod can still delete it.. right?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yes, but we shouldn't have to wait for a moderator to delete something which was already deleted elsewhere. A better suggestion is to just delete the migrated question too if the question gets deleted on the origin site after a rejection.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd For what I understood, the question in the receiving site is locked to avoid any further migration; if the question in the original site is deleted, that is a reason more to delete it in the site where it was migrated. There is no need to require a moderator, when 3 10K users can delete it.

Comment: Hm, too localized shouldn't really reject the migration in the first place, I thought that only happened for off topic / not a real question closures.

Comment: @YannisRizos anything but "duplicate" or "migrate" rejects a migraiton